# Do compilers automatically use move semantics when a movable object is used for the last time?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics

I've been studying rvalue references lately and came to a conclusion that it's quite advantageous to use pass-by-value everywhere where complete copy of an object will be made (for complete justification see e.g. [How to reduce redundant code when adding rvalue reference operator overloads?](/a/2749285) and [Want speed? Pass by value!](/q/)), because the compiler can automatically optimize a copy away in cases such as `f(std::move(a));`, where `f` is defined as `void f(A a);`.

One negative consequence of pass-by-value-everywhere is that all the code becomes littered with `std::move` even in simple cases such as:

```
void Object::value(A a) 
{
    value_ = std::move(a);
}
```

Obviously, if I wrote only the following:

```
void Object::value(A a) 
{
    value_ = a;
}
```

it shouldn't be hard for the compiler to recognize that `a` is near the end of its lifetime even without the hint and not to penalize me with additional copy. In fact, the compiler should be able to recognize this even in complex functions.

The questions:

1. Is this optimization allowed by the C++0x Standard?
2. Do the compilers employ it? Even in complex cases, i.e. the function consists from more than one line?
3. How reliable is this optimization, i.e. can I expect the compiler to utilize it as much as I expect the compiler to apply Return Value Optimization?

Comment: "use pass-by-value everywhere" -- Please, **don't do this**. Only do it if you'd make a copy of the parameter inside the function anyways, not just everywhere!

Comment: @jons34yp is it not better to always pass-by-constant-reference?

Comment: @Yet: It is better to judge for each case what suits best.

Comment: The problem with passing by value everywhere is that in case you call the function with an object which cannot be moved is that you'll have to create a copy. So it's better to pass by reference if you are not going to change the object anyway.

Comment: @Xeo: No, I definitely won't use pass by value everywhere _literally_. Thanks for pointing this out, I clarified the question.

Comment: @Yet, RedX: If I use pass-by-constant-reference the data will be automatically copied regardless of the optimization possibilities. Pass-by-value allows to optimize the copy away when the function parameter is a rvalue.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y just for curiosity in which way is it better to pass-by-value instead of pass-by-constant reference? Is it in multithreaded applications?

Comment: @Yet: As Xeo already mentioned, one instance is when you would copy the parameter anyway. Pass-by-value gives the compiler the opportunity to do copy-ellision.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is this optimization allowed by the C++0x Standard?

No.

> Do the compilers employ it? Even in
>   complex cases, i.e. the function
>   consists from more than one line?

No.

> How reliable is this optimization,
>   i.e. can I expect the compiler to
>   utilize it as much as I expect the
>   compiler to apply Return Value
>   Optimization?

You should decorate `A(const A&)` and `A(A&&)` with print statements and run test cases of interest to you.  Don't forget to test lvalue arguments if those use cases are part of your design.

The correct answers will depend upon how expensive the copy and move of `A` are,how many arguments `Object::value` actually has, and how much code repetition you're willing to put up with.

Finally, be **very suspicious** of any guideline that contains words like "always" or "everywhere".  E.g. I use `goto` every once in a while.  But other programmers have words like "never" associated with `goto`.  But every once in a while, you can't beat a `goto` for both speed and clarity.

There will be times you should favor a pair of `foo(const A&) foo(A&&)` over `foo(A)`.  And times you won't.  Your experiments with decorated copy and move members will guide you.

Comment: I don't see why not. We have to create a model of execution *somewhere*, and I think in that model we'll find that it doesn't make sense to keep a value around after its last use. Ergo if it is indeed the last use and that last use is assignment/initialization, we can move it instead of copy it. This would be without loss because in our model moving is never more expensive than copying, and moving is intended to transfer a value. (That is, it operates under the as-if principle.)

Comment: It is difficult to define "last use".  Even with the definition we currently have, it is possible to detect the implicit-move optimization (and thus it really isn't an optimization).  But compromises were reached.  What helped in reaching those compromises was tying it to the return value optimization (which is also detectable).  Example: put a `B b(a);` prior to your "last use".  Now if you move from `a`, `b.~B()` can detect the move by storing a reference to `a`.